# Laravel Eloquent ORM many-to-many Search Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I am using Laravel v3, with Eloquent, and a MySQL database for this application

I have an employee database, with a search form that displays a list of the employees that match the search criteria. You can fill out one or many fields, and it will match on all the filled out fields only. As seen below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttfhr.png

The search all functions correctly, except for I just added the multiselect for the "Training". An employee can have zero to many training certificates attached to them. If the user was to search for first name "Matt", and check off "CSTS" under the training search criteria, the list would show all employees that have a first name similar to Matt, and also have CSTS training.

Database schema is as follows:

```
user
--id
--first_name
--last_name
--job_title_id
etc...


training
--id
--name
--issused_date
--expiry_date

user_training
--id
--user_id
--training_id
```

The Model's for User and Training are as follows:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

  public static $table = 'user';

  public function training(){
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('training','user_training');
  }


class Training extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'training';


  public function users(){
      return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('user','user_training');
  }



}
```

I have the following code, for the function search, and what I tried for the training:

```
Route::post('(:bundle)/list', function() {

$search = new StdClass(); 
$search->first_name = Input::get('first_name');
$search->last_name = Input::get('last_name');
$search->job_titles = Input::get('job_titles'); // array of ids/returns null if none selected
$search->training = Input::get('training'); // array of ids/returns null if none selected
$search->city = Input::get('city');
$search->province = Input::get('province');
$search->phone = Input::get('phone');
$search->status = Input::get('status');
$search->gender = Input::get('gender');
$search->hire_from_date = Input::get('hire_from_date');
$search->hire_to_date = Input::get('hire_to_date');
$search->current_location = Input::get('current_location');
$search->role = Input::get('role');

Session::put('search', $search); // so we can access inside query builder sub-functions


$query = User::where('active', '=', true);

if(!empty($search->training)) { // one or many


    $query = User::with(array('training' => function($query) {
        $s_search = Session::get('search');
        //$query->where_in('training.id', $s_search->training);
        //foreach($s_search->training as $id) {
        //  $query->where('training.id', '=', $id);
        //}
    }));
}


//$query = User::join('user_training', 'user.id', '=', 'user_training.user_id');
//$query->join('user_training', 'user.id', '=', 'user_training.user_id');
//$query->join('training', 'training.id', '=', 'user_training.training_id');

if(!empty($search->first_name)) { $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search->first_name . '%'); }
if(!empty($search->last_name)) { $query->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search->last_name . '%'); }

if(!empty($search->city)) { $query->where('city', 'LIKE', '%' . $search->city . '%'); }
if(!empty($search->province)) { $query->where('province_id', '=', $search->province); }

if(!empty($search->gender)) { $query->where('gender', '=', $search->gender); }
if(!empty($search->phone)) { $query->where('phone_1', 'LIKE', '%' . $search->phone . '%'); }

if(!empty($search->status)) { $query->where('status_id', '=', $search->status); }
if(!empty($search->role)) { $query->where('role_id', '=', $search->role); }
if(!empty($search->current_location)) { $query->where('location_id', '=', $search->current_location); }

if(!empty($search->hire_from_date)) // "after"
    $query->where('hire_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($search->hire_from_date)));

if(!empty($search->hire_to_date))  // "before"
    $query->where('hire_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime($search->hire_to_date)));

if(!empty($search->job_titles)) { // one or many
    $query->where(function($query){
        $s_search = Session::get('search');
        foreach($s_search->job_titles as $id) {
            $query->or_where('job_title_id', '=', $id);
        }
    });
}



$query->order_by('last_name');

$user_list = $query->distinct()->get();
$user_count = $query->count();

var_dump($user_list); die;


if(Input::get('action') == 'export') {

    if(Permission::check("Export Users CSV")) {
        $now = new DateTime();
        return Response::download(User::get_group_csv($user_list), date_format(new DateTime(), 'Y-m-d') . '_User_Export.csv');
    }

}
```

The "$user->training" comes in as a simple array of id's, which matches up with the Training->id table

The Job Title search functions correctly with the multiselect, but the job_title_id is in the User table, not a relationship.

I have tried looping, manually joining, using eager load, using Eloquent's "with", all with no success. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is a lot of information there finishing with the words "Can someone point me in the right direction?". But I do not understand what you want to achieve, what direction do you want to be pointed in?

Comment: The end goal is to be able to select any number of "Training" items in the multiselect, and when you click search, it will return only the users that have those training certificates

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to use the session to get variables into your anonymous functions. Try using "uses" instead.

```
// $search already defined

$query = User::where('active', '=', true);

if(!empty($search->training)) { // one or many
    $query = User::with(array('training' => function($query) uses ($search) {
        // Now you can use $search in this context
    }));
}
```

}

Also, you are using lower case strings for your relationships but the models/classes are actually capitalized so they should be like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'user';

    public function training(){
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Training', 'user_training');
    }
}

class Training extends Eloquent {

    public static $table = 'training';

    public function users(){
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User', 'user_training');
    }
}
```

Third, you are declaring "$query = User::where('active', '=', true);" and then overwriting it. Maybe you are looking for this:

```
if (!empty($search->training)) { // one or many
    $query = User::with(array('training' => function($query) uses ($search) {
        // Now you can use $search in this context
        $query->where_in('training.id', $search->training);
    }));
} else {
    $query = User::with(array());
}
$query = $query->where('active', '=', true);
```

I could give more insight but I'm not 100% on what your end goal is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the uses keyword, that makes sense I just never saw that in the laravel documentation.

Comment: The end goal is to be able to select any number of "Training" items in the multiselect, and when you click search, it will return only the users that have those training certificates.

Comment: Can I use the  'uses' keyowrd in the job_title as well? Deosnt seem to be working. Its a similar situation with the 'where' subfunction.

<!-- language: lang-php -->
    if(!empty($search->job_titles)) { // one or many
       $query->where(function($query) uses ($search) {
        foreach($search->job_titles as $id) {
         $query->or_where('job_title_id', '=', $id);
        }
       });
      }

Comment: Quick note, the keyword is 'use' not 'uses'